# Submit a POST request from a Django View and send response to a template

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, jwt

I'm working on a Django(1.10) project and now creating a rest API for my project using Django Rest Framework.I have setup JWT token and now I want to provide a template to the user where he can generate a token.
Here's the URL for auth token:

```
url(r'^api-token-auth/', obtain_jwt_token)
```

And I want to send a post request to this URL from a view which loads to generate  a token but it required user's `username` and `password`.

How can i pass current user's `username` and `password` ?

Here's my view:

```
class GetApiAuthToken(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return render(request, 'dockerDep/getApiAuthToken.html', {})

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            post_data = request.POST.copy()
            post_data.update({'user': request.user.pk})
            payload = {'username': request.user.username, 'password': request.user.password}
            r = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api-token-auth/', params=payload)
            return HttpResponse('Get token auth request and data is as: {}'.format(r.text))
```

and here's the template from which user can click on a button to generate a token:

```
<div class="col-md-9 content">
        <div class="world-map" style="width: 100%; margin-left:2%">
            <h3> Get your Authorization Token to use REST Api :</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6" style="margin-top: 20%;  margin-left: 25%;"><br>
            <form action="{% url 'users:getApiAuthToken' %}" method="post" id="getTokenForm">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <a href="" style="text-decoration: none; color: white;">
                <button type="submit" class="btn waves-effect waves-light  pull-right" value="Submit" id="enableApi" style="padding-right: 10%; font-size: 20px;"><i
                            class="material-icons left">casino</i>  Generate Api Token!</button></a>
            </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here's i'm sending a an AJAX POST reuqest to the view:

```
$(document).on('submit', '#getTokenForm', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: '{% url 'users:getApiAuthToken' %}',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

How can I pass user's credentials? or is there a better approach to allow a user to generate a token?